# Error initializing task AspNetCompiler: Not registered task AspNetCompiler

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mono, xbuild

I am trying to build my .NET 4.5.1 solution under Mono 4.0.1 but receive the error: `Error initializing task AspNetCompiler: Not registered task AspNetCompiler`

However, I see that there is a AspNetCompiler.cs file  in the mono repo:
https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Microsoft.Build.Tasks/Microsoft.Build.Tasks/AspNetCompiler.cs

Is there a way I can register the AspNetCompiler task so my sln will build?